# Excel 2010 - filter pivot table by pattern

Tags: excel, excel-2010, ssas, pivot-table

in Excel 2010 I am trying to analyze some data from an external analysis service.

In a pivot table I am trying to filter the report by one field which has multiple values separated by a comma. These look like this:

> AB, CD1, EF1-5
>
> AB, CD1,3, EF1
>
> BCD, EFG
>
> EXG, HIJ, CD1
>
> ...

So as you can see, there are hundreds of values in any possible order and no fixed scheme.

What I'm trying to achieve is to select all the fields which have a key beginning with an *E* (*EF1-5, EF1, EFG, EXG, ...*) and those beginning with *H*. These literals are never part of another key, so I could imagine using wildcards and creating a filter pattern like

> *E* OR *H*
>
> contains(E) || contains(H)

or equal.
Is there any way to do this?

With best regards,

Babbage

**edit**: I've tried selecting some of the Keys manually by deselecting all and searching e.g. for *EF1-5* to select them. But even then there are more than 10000 Keys with *EF1-5* at different locations. So I can't even select them all. The plan was to create two or more pivot tables and merge the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the drop down filter that you have in the pivot table, click on `Select Multiple Items` and deselect `ALL`. Then in the search bar (again at the pivot table filter) write `*e*` and select `add current selection to filter`. Repeat for `*h*`.

Do not forget to select `add current selection to filter` in both cases.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. There are more than 10000 Keys containing *E* and Excel can't handle this amount.

Comment: I would suggest then to drag the filter as a Row Label in the pivot and create a column as Key with the following function: `=(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("e",A5)))+NOT(ISERROR(FIND("h",A5))))>0` and then pivot the pivot, use as filter the Key and set it to True. (I am assuming the the column with your `AB, CD1, EF1-5` and `EXG, HIJ, CD1` start from cell A5

Comment: That worked. Kind of dirty, but with a macro it does what I want it to do. Thank you!